# Make a progress bar out of a image in Blend

Tags: c#, image, progress-bar, blend

I've been trying to get a image as a progress bar in Blend to use in a programm to see how much time is left, and to fitt the whole GUI i want a costume progress bar instead of a default green one, I've got 2 images i want to use, the cointainer holding the bar and de green bar itself. only problem is that i don't know how to set these things.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the color of the Progress Bar unless you disable the visual style of the Application. My advice is to create a custom control, a simple way to do it is to fill a piece of rectangle every time the progress changes. 
So use a Panel as container and a PictureBox to draw on it docked to the container. In the Paint Event of the PictureBox check if the progress changed (progress stored as int in a property or field) and if it did draw the remaining rectangle:

```
//check if progress changed ex. if( lastProg != this.Progress ) 
using ( Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage( pb.Image ) ) {
    using( Brush brush = new SolidBrush( myColor ) ) {
        //calculate width and x here
        g.FillRectangle( brush, x, 0, width, pb.Heigth );
    }
}
```

You need to know that it's proportional to its width so if its size may change because the window is resized by the user you have to scale it as well.
After all you could add some other visual styles so when the progress is really slow it feels still working. 
Well that is my solution, if you need a sample here is it [by CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6905/Color-ProgressBar).